# Has Mark Hamill talked about his line delivery in The Last Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, the-last-jedi, actors

Specifically, I was impressed with his clearly deliberate choice to deliver lines

> in a higher-pitched, excited, and more adolescent voice in order to call back to his performance in *A New Hope* and demonstrate that the younger pre-Jedi boy full of wonder is still a part of him.

In particular this was conspicuous when he

> reunites with his three old friends -- Chewbacca, R2-D2, and the Millenium Falcon.

## Has Mark Hamill or Rian Johnson commented on these choices?

Answer (score 1):

Not as of yet.

To date (as of 12/27/17) there has been no public statement about Hamill's delivery of any of the lines in the movie by anyone involved in production.

Most likely there will not be, unless it is in the Commentary tracks we can assume will be shipped with the DVD/Blu-Ray editions of The Last Jedi.